# AHK shortcuts for Alt+Space in Windows

Tags: autohotkey

running AHK in Windows 10, and I'm trying to create shortcuts for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu. Specifically, I often use this sequence:

1. Press keys <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (bring up the window menu)
2. Press key <kbd>S</kbd> (select Size to resize)
3. Press key <kbd>Left</kbd> (now moving the mouse is resizing your window horizontally)
4. Press key <kbd>Up</kbd> (now moving the mouse is resizing your window in all directions)

Once this sequence is pressed, you can move your mouse to resize the active window as if you click-dragged the top-right corner, without having to hunt for that corner. (to finalize the resizing you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> of <kbd>LeftMouseKey</kbd>, or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to abort). I'd like to get to this state with a single shortcut.

Here is my current script, binding to <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

```
;resize window from Top-Left
#^+1::
SendInput !{Space}
Sleep 100
SendInput s
Sleep 100
SendInput {Left}+{Up}
Return
```

It works mostly, but sometimes the active window will consume the `s {Left} {Up}` commands, rather than the popup menu. Thus, sometimes this shortcut will result in the active window like VSCode having the "s" character and the cursor 1 line up from before (as if typing `s {Left} {Up}`), and a visible <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu.

I initially used Sleep 10 and thought Sleep 100 would fix this, but it didn't. The shortcut already feels slow with 2x Sleep 100 built in.

I'd like to test if the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu is open before `SendInput s` and preferably make sure I'm sending to the menu rather than the main application.

Comment: If the window is maximized the script does not perform as intended. Try to minimize the window first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce the problem using your method. Perhaps try using `Send`, `SendEvent`, `SendPlay`, `SendRaw`, `#InstallKeybdHook`, `#UseHook`

Alternatively, use Autohotkey's `WinMove` statement:

**This resizes the active window such that the upper left hand corner is at the current mouse position**

```cpp
#^+1::
  CoordMode Mouse, screen
  id := WinExist("A")
  WinGetPos x, y, width, height, ahk_id %id%
  MouseGetPos mx, my
  neww := width  + x - mx
  newh := height + y - my
  WinMove % "ahk_id" id,, mx, my, neww, newh
  return
```

Answer (score 1):

The menu itself is `ahk_class #32768`, so waiting for it to exist seems to work for me.

```
#^+1::
Send , !{space}
WinWait , ahk_class #32768 ,, 1 ; Waits 1s for menu to exist
If !ErrorLevel ; ErrorLevel is 0 if menu exists
    Send , s{left}+{up}
Return
```

[Jim U's alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55032721/4575793) is a more reliable way of doing what you're trying to achieve, but this will make what you currently have work.

Comment: Thanks Evan, the WinWait approach will come in very handy for scripting other menus. I went with Jim's answer for this problem since it's a more reliable way to resize the application window.